# Extract numbers preceding by slash (\)only

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I would extract all the numbers preceding by(`\`) only using regex :

```
filer = 'in this \002eld has established some theoretical guidelines. 
Besides such immediate bene\002ts of lower costs 24 [1], [3], [5].'
```

I tried the following :

```
ss = set(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', filer))
print ss
```

but all the numbers were returned.

The output :
    set(['24', '1', '3', '5'])

and notice the wanted numbers weren't returned

Answer (score 1):

you could try look-behind like so

```
(?<=\\)\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can simply do:

```
>>> import re
>>> filer = 'in this \002eld has established some theoretical guidelines. Besides such immediate bene\002ts of lower costs 24 [1], [3], [5].'
>>> re.findall(r"\\\d+", filer)
['\\002', '\\002']
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Your regexp is wrong as it's matching all digits within a word boundary, i.e.:

```
>>> s r'matches: 123 \456 789 ; but not: \321aoeu ao654 ao\987oa'
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', s)
['123', '456', '789']
```

so in your regexp it won't be matching `\002eld` or `\002ts` because of the extra characters on the right. But it would also match the `\` numbers, if it was:

```
'in this \002 eld has established some theoretical guidelines. 
Besides such immediate bene\002 ts of lower costs 24 [1], [3], [5].'
```

Have a look at the following representation (click to play), so you'll better understand why it's matching only the numbers at the end:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define your input as raw string or otherwise `\002` in your string would be converted to other unicode character.

```
>>> filer = r'in this \002eld has established some theoretical guidelines. Besides such immediate bene\002ts of lower costs 24 [1], [3], [5].'
>>> re.findall(r'\\(\d+)', filer)
['002', '002']
>>> filer = 'in this \002eld has established some theoretical guidelines. Besides such immediate bene\002ts of lower costs 24 [1], [3], [5].'
>>> re.findall(r'\\(\d+)', filer)
[]
```